# Why only once next function running in generators recursion?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, generator

In my think. I have to run `next` function in  many times,by below code.

code environment:**Google Chrome browser. version: 63.0.3239.132.**

```
const a = [1,2,3,[4,5],6,[7,8]];

function *fun(array){
    for(let i = 0;i<array.length;i++){
        if(Array.isArray(array[i])){
            yield *fun(array[i]);
        }
    }
}

console.log(fun(a).next().done);//true
```

In usually generators function,just one `yield`.It have to run twice `next` function then `done` become `true`.

For Example:

```
function *foo() {
    yield 1;
}

const iterator = foo();
console.log(iterator.next().done);//false
console.log(iterator.next().done);//true
```

Why in the recursion Example,it just run once then iterator had done?

By the way, this doubt from the book which name is `You-Dont-Know-JS` in `chapter 3`.

Comment: Why did you put `;` after `}` from the if clause?

Comment: My be It is my code habit?It right or mistake?

Comment: It is a mistake.

Comment: In your code, there is nothing to yield when a value is not an array. 

When your iterate over your first array and found an array as item, you delegate to a new generator (the same but on the array value).

`yield *fun` means you delegate to a new iterator.

What behaviour are you waiting for ?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `yield` statement for the items that are not arrays:

```js
const a = [1,2,3,[4,5],6,[7,8]];

function *fun(array){
    for(let i = 0;i<array.length;i++){
        if(Array.isArray(array[i])){
            yield *fun(array[i]);
        } else { // if the item is not an array
            yield array[i];
        }
    }
}

const f = fun(a);

console.log(f.next());
console.log(f.next());
console.log(f.next());
console.log(f.next());
console.log(f.next());
console.log(f.next());
console.log(f.next());
console.log(f.next());
console.log(f.next());
```